# How to Implement Infinite Scroll in Next JS SSG?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I created a markdown blog by following the Next Js documentation and Using Typescript. To Fetch a list of blog posts I used `getStaticProps` as the [docs](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/data-fetching/implement-getstaticprops) suggested. I tried with some npm packages, it's not working, or maybe I didn't know how to set up perfectly.

If there is a good **plugin** or **custom hooks**, Please tell me how can I add the infinite scroll feature in Next Js static site generation.

Project source code is available in this GitHub repository: https://github.com/vercel/next-learn-starter/blob/master/typescript-final/pages/index.tsx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I did some research and created my own react hooks to implement infinite scroll in Next JS. So, I am answering my question.

**If anyone has a better method, please don't forget to share it here.**

I found two working methods. First One done by using `innerHeight`, `scrollTop`, `offsetHeight` values. It worked perfectly, but somehow I felt this is not the correct way to do that. Please correct me if I am wrong.

The second method was to asynchronously observe changes in the intersection of a target element by [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). First, I created a pagination custom react hook to limit my blog posts then I used IntersectionObserver to fetch the blog posts of the next pages.

usePagination.tsx:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function usePagination(data, itemsPerPage: number) {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);

  const maxPage = Math.ceil(data.length / itemsPerPage);

  function currentData() {
    const begin = (currentPage - 1) * itemsPerPage;
    const end = begin + itemsPerPage;
    return data.slice(null, end);
  }

  function next() {
    setCurrentPage((currentPage) => Math.min(currentPage + 1, maxPage));
  }

  return { next, currentData, currentPage, maxPage };
}

export default usePagination;
```

Index.tsx:

```
import { GetStaticProps } from "next";
import { getSortedPostsData } from "../lib/posts";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import usePagination from "../lib/Hooks/usePagination";
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Home({
  allPostsData,
}: {
  allPostsData: {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    date: string;
    cover: string;
  }[];
}) {
  const { next, currentPage, currentData, maxPage } = usePagination(
    allPostsData,
    8
  );
  const currentPosts = currentData();
  const [element, setElement] = useState(null);

  const observer = useRef<IntersectionObserver>();
  const prevY = useRef(0);
  useEffect(() => {
    observer.current = new IntersectionObserver(
      (entries) => {
        const firstEntry = entries[0];
        const y = firstEntry.boundingClientRect.y;

        if (prevY.current > y) {
          next();
        }
        prevY.current = y;
      },
      { threshold: 0.5 }
    );
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentElement = element;
    const currentObserver = observer.current;

    if (currentElement) {
      currentObserver.observe(currentElement);
    }

    return () => {
      if (currentElement) {
        currentObserver.unobserve(currentElement);
      }
    };
  }, [element]);
  return (
    <Layout>

      <article className="w-full mt-12 flex flex-wrap items-center justify-center">
        {currentPosts &&
          currentPosts.map(({ id, title, date, cover }) => (
            <div key={id} // ......
            </div>
          ))}
      </article>
      {currentPage !== maxPage ? (
        <h1 ref={setElement}>Loading Posts...</h1>
      ) : (
        <h1>No more posts available...</h1>
      )}
    </Layout>
  );
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const allPostsData = getSortedPostsData();

  return {
    props: {
      allPostsData,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: this is nice. But won't it increase the initial data for the index page as more posts add up?